# Page not found (404) No Invoice matches the given query

Tags: python, django, web

I am building a store in django. And I connected the store to a test payment gateway, and I can add products to the shopping cart, and do the test payment locally. But the problem occurs when I do a test payment and I have to be redirected to the callback.html page and I get an error.

Image of the error that occurred
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r59F7.jpg)

views.py file in the shop application:

```
# Views.py in shop app
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from . import models
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from zeep import Client, client
import requests
import json


# Index function
def index(request):
    product_list = models.Product.objects.all()[:5]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'product_list': product_list})


# Checkout function
@login_required
def checkout(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = models.Order.objects.create(customer=request.user)
        for item in cart:
            models.OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                            product=item['product'],
                                            product_price=item['price'],
                                            product_count=item['product_count'],
                                            product_cost=Decimal(item['product_count']) * Decimal(item['price']))
        order.customer = request.user
        order.save()
        cart.clear()
        return render(request, 'order_detail.html', {'order': order})
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', {'cart': cart})


# Product function
def product(request, pk):
    product_detail = get_object_or_404(models.Product, id=pk)
    cart_add_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'product.html', {'product_detail': product_detail,
                                            'cart_add_product_form': cart_add_product_form})


# Store function
def store(request):
    return render(request, 'store.html')


# DecimalEncoder class
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)


# Create variables for to_bank function
MERCHANT = '*******-****-****-****-***********'
ZP_API_REQUEST = 'https://sandbox.banktest.ir/zarinpal/api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/request.json'
ZP_API_VERIFY = 'https://sandbox.banktest.ir/zarinpal/api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/verify.json'
ZP_API_STARTPAY = 'https://sandbox.banktest.ir/zarinpal/www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/{authority}'
callbackurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/'
mobile = '0213124'
email = 'test@gmail.com'
description = 'Test'


# To bank function
def to_bank(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(models.Order, id=order_id)
    order_items = models.OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    amount = 0
    for item in order_items:
        amount += item.product_cost
    req_data = {
        "merchant_id": MERCHANT,
        "amount": amount,
        "callback_url": callbackurl,
        "description": description,
        "metadata": {"mobile": mobile, "email": email}
    }
    req_header = {"accept": "application/json",
                  "content-type": "application/json"}
    req = requests.post(url=ZP_API_REQUEST, data=json.dumps(
        req_data, cls=DecimalEncoder), headers=req_header)
    authority = req.json()['data']['authority']
    if len(req.json()['errors']) == 0:
        return redirect(ZP_API_STARTPAY.format(authority=authority))
    else:
        e_code = req.json()['errors']['code']
        e_message = req.json()['errors']['message']
        return HttpResponse(f"Error code: {e_code}, Error Message: {e_message}")


# Verify function
def verify(request, order_id):
    amount = 0
    order = get_object_or_404(models.Order, id=order_id)
    order_items = models.OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    for item in order_items:
        amount += item.product_cost
    t_status = request.GET.get('Status')
    t_authority = request.GET['Authority']
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
        req_header = {"accept": "application/json",
                      "content-type": "application/json"}
        req_data = {
            "merchant_id": MERCHANT,
            "amount": amount,
            "authority": t_authority
        }
        req = requests.post(url=ZP_API_VERIFY, data=json.dumps(req_data, cls=DecimalEncoder), headers=req_header)
        if len(req.json()['errors']) == 0:
            t_status = req.json()['data']['code']
            if t_status == 100:
                return HttpResponse('Transaction success.\nRefID: ' + str(
                    req.json()['data']['ref_id']
                ))
            elif t_status == 101:
                return HttpResponse('Transaction submitted : ' + str(
                    req.json()['data']['message']
                ))
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Transaction failed.\nStatus: ' + str(
                    req.json()['data']['message']
                ))
        else:
            e_code = req.json()['errors']['code']
            e_message = req.json()['errors']['message']
            return HttpResponse(f"Error code: {e_code}, Error Message: {e_message}")
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Transaction failed or canceled by user')


# Callback function
def callback(request):
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'NOK':
        authority = request.GET.get('Authority')
        invoice = get_object_or_404(models.Invoice, authority=authority)
        amount = 0
        order = invoice.order
        order_items = models.OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
        for item in order_items:
            amount += item.product_cost
        result = client.service.PaymentVerification(MERCHANT, authority, amount)
        if result.Status == 100:
            return render(request, 'callback.html', {'invoice': invoice})
        else:
            return HttpResponse('error ' + str(result.Status))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error ')
```

urls.py file in shop application:

```
# Urls.py in shop app
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/', views.product, name='product'),
    path('store/', views.store, name='store'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('to-bank/<int:order_id>/', views.to_bank, name='to_bank'),
    path('callback/', views.callback, name='callback'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py in shop application:

```
# Models.py in shop app
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/product/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('create_time',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product', args=[self.id])


class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    product_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    invoice_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    authority = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('failed', 'Failed'),
        ('completed', 'Completed')
    )
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='pending')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

callback.html file in shop application:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Callback {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <!-- BREADCRUMB -->
        <div id="breadcrumb" class="section">
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="breadcrumb-header">Payment Detail</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /BREADCRUMB -->

        <!-- SECTION -->
        <div class="section">
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Order Details -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 order-details">
                        <div class="section-title text-center">
                            <h3 class="title">Thank you</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-summary">
                            <p>Your Invoice number: {{ invoice.id }}</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /Order Details -->
                </div>
                <!-- /row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /SECTION -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It seems the error occurred on the third line of the callback function in views.py. Have you checked if the content of the authority variable is correct ?

Comment: Probably the line ‘invoice = get_object_or_404(models.Invoice, authority=authority)’ is raising the exception, because this invoice doesn’t exist

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now that I checked and used the command `print(authority)`, I got this output  A00000000000000000000000000000463388
Not Found: /callback/
[22/Oct/2022 15:30:09] "GET /callback/?Authority=A00000000000000000000000000000463388&Status=NOK HTTP/1.1" 404 3438

Comment: The problem was solved. The problem was that I had to write Authority in lowercase letters. Thanks